# How and when exactly CompositionLocal sets values implicitly?

Tags: kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I'm trying to understand how `CompositionLocal` actually sets values implicitly and what requiremnts need to be met so that it works, but Android's documentation about [Locally scoped data with CompositionLocal](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal) isn't helping.

There is an example where the color of a `Text` is being changed by assigning a new value to the `color` parameter.

```
// Some composable deep in the hierarchy of MaterialTheme
@Composable
fun SomeTextLabel(labelText: String) {
    Text(
        text = labelText,
        // `primary` is obtained from MaterialTheme's
        // LocalColors CompositionLocal
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
    )
}
```

But this is not implicit if you need to set it this way!

Then they show another example where they change the `ContentAlpha` via the `CompositionLocalProvider` and here the `Text` *suddenly* can use the new value implicitly even though they write that *CompositionLocal is what the Material theme uses under the hood.* so why doesn't it work with the first example?

```
@Composable
fun CompositionLocalExample() {
    MaterialTheme { // MaterialTheme sets ContentAlpha.high as default
        Column {
            Text("Uses MaterialTheme's provided alpha")
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
                Text("Medium value provided for LocalContentAlpha")
                Text("This Text also uses the medium value")
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.disabled) {
                    DescendantExample()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DescendantExample() {
    // CompositionLocalProviders also work across composable functions
    Text("This Text uses the disabled alpha now")
}
```

---

There's also a 3rd example where they show how to [create your own `CompositionLocal`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal#creating-apis), but here agian, they **explicitly** set the `Card`'s `elevation` parameter!

```
@Composable
fun SomeComposable() {
    // Access the globally defined LocalElevations variable to get the
    // current Elevations in this part of the Composition
    Card(elevation = LocalElevations.current.card) {
        // Content
    }
}
```

Didn't they just create the `CompositionLocalProvider` to avoid doing this?

```
            // Bind elevation as the value for LocalElevations
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalElevations provides elevations) {
                // ... Content goes here ...
                // This part of Composition will see the `elevations` instance
                // when accessing LocalElevations.current
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Composable
fun CompositionLocalExample() {
    MaterialTheme { // MaterialTheme sets ContentAlpha.high as default
        Column {
            Text("Uses MaterialTheme's provided alpha")
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
                Text("Medium value provided for LocalContentAlpha")
                Text("This Text also uses the medium value")
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.disabled) {
                    DescendantExample()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this sample `Text` sets alpha in [source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Text.kt?q=Text&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport) using `LocalContentAlpha.current` value with

```
val localContentColor = LocalContentColor.current
val localContentAlpha = LocalContentAlpha.current
val overrideColorOrUnspecified: Color = if (color.isSpecified) {
    color
} else if (style.color.isSpecified) {
    style.color
} else {
    localContentColor.copy(localContentAlpha)
}
```

because of that changing value `LocalContentAlpha` provides changes the alpha `Text` gets.

As in third example where elevation is set with

> Consuming the CompositionLocal CompositionLocal.current returns the
> value provided by the nearest CompositionLocalProvider that provides a
> value to that CompositionLocal:

```
@Composable
fun SomeComposable() {
    // Access the globally defined LocalElevations variable to get the
    // current Elevations in this part of the Composition
    Card(elevation = LocalElevations.current.card) {
        // Content
    }
}
```

Also for instance with Icon which has default tint

```
tint: Color = LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current)
```

You can apply LocalContentAlpha or LocalContentColor to change default tint value or explicitly change param itself.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {

    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {

        // Default icon
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Favorite,
            contentDescription = null
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Favorite,
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = Color.Green
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier.alpha(.3f),
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Favorite,
            tint = Color.Green,
            contentDescription = null
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

        // Icon uses tint: Color = LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current)
        // changing it also changes default tint
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides Color.Green) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Favorite,
                contentDescription = null
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides .3f) {
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides Color.Green) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Favorite,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! So the magic lies in the source code already using some the general `LocalX` providers and when I want to change something else then I need to do this myself and it won't be autowired and there's no way of achieving this. Would that be correct?

Comment: If that Composable reads any LocalContent value you can change it using `CompositionLocalProvider ` otherwise you do it via modifiers or other params.

Comment: If a default Composable doesn't have way to access `LocalX` you defined, you can provide any Composable with elevation as in that example, `SomeComposable `, then anywhere you use `CompositionLocalProvider` will be using elevation assigned in that provider